# Reverse Terminal Command prompt

Tags: command-line

I was wondering if there is a way to reverse the Linux terminal command prompt to reverse order?  Currently, the system terminal goes in a bottom to top.  I was wondering if there is something I can do to set the prompt to go top to bottom.  I am not sure if I would like it but I wanted to see if I could change it to see if I like it and, if not, change it back.

Comment: I think that's a matter of your terminal emulator, which one do you talk about here?

Comment: https://www.unix.com/unix-desktop-questions-and-answers/145379-how-do-you-reverse-terminal-command-line-top.html  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324878/terminal-to-display-from-top-to-down

Comment: *"Currently, the system terminal goes in a bottom to top."* I have no idea what this is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. I had to look it up in one of my text books since I couldn't remember how to do it from memory.

**Moving The Cursor**

> Escape codes can be used to position the cursor. This is commonly used to provide clock or some other kind of information at a different location on the screen such as an upper corner each time the prompt is drawn. Here is a list of the escape codes that position the cursor:

[image: cursor movement escape sequences]

You would do this by modifying your *prompt string* which is a environment variable.

Heres an example

```
# This is what my prompt string looks like
$ echo $PS1
[\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]: \[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]]\$
```

Explanation

> [...] The [ and ] sequences are used to encapsulate non-printing characters.
>   An ANSI escape code begins with an octal 033 (the code generated by the escape key)
>   followed by an optional character attribute followed by an instruction. For example, the
>   code to set the text color to normal (attribute = 0), black text is:
>   \033[0;30m

Once you've got your set up, you can test it out to see how it works before making it permanent.

```
# backup your prompt string
$ oldps1="$PS1"
# The create a new one
$ PS1="Your Prompt String Goes Here"
# then export it to see the results
# note that this is usually global for the current shell
$ export PS1
```

Hope this helps. You can visit [here](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/index.html) to see more info!

This information came from *The Linux Command Line by William E. Shotts, Jr.*. You can support his work by buying a physical copy from [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1593273894) or download a free copy from his [website](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php).

The *[Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)* also has an cursory explanation on [how to manipulate the cursor](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/terminalccmds.html). You can find [in-depth examples here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html).